# do we say "the balloon is popped" or "the balloon has been popped" or "the balloon was popped" according to the time that we utter it?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, tense, phrase-choice

[image]

Now, your balloon was broken a few minutes ago.

do we say "**the balloon is popped**" or "**the balloon has been popped**" or "**the balloon was popped**" according to the time that we utter it?

For example,

**A few minutes later?**

**A few days later?**

**A few months later?**

**A few years later?**

Comment: Unless someone pops it with a pin, we usually say "the balloon popped."

Comment: I would say "The balloon burst" (or "has [been] burst" if it had only just happened).

Answer (score 1):

If the balloon popped by itself, then:

> the balloon popped.
> the balloon (has) burst.

If the balloon was actively popped by a person:

> Derek popped the balloon.
> The balloon was popped.
> The balloon has been popped.

The following does not look like common usage, since popped and burst are more often used as verbs than as adjectives:

> the balloon **is** popped *

If you prefer an adjective, then ripped, ruptured, broken. Or maybe a "popped balloon" (an attributive adjective).

What about - **A few minutes later? A few days later? A few months later? A few years later**?

If it just happened a second ago, then you could say:

> The balloon just popped.
> The balloon popped.

If it happened a few minutes or hours ago:

> The balloon popped.
> The balloon was popped.
> The balloon has been popped.

If it happened a year ago:

> This looks like a popped/broken balloon.

Comment: How do we know the past participles of which verbs are not often used as adjectives to express states?

Comment: @Tom I don't know a shortcut other than "massive input" of the target language being studied.